# Contracting Party has a legal right of rescission - what possibilities are possible, e.g. Procedere of Reverse Transaction

Tags: transactions

if one party has a legal right to rescission; how can the blockchain deal with it?
Is it possible to implement a reverse transaction if 
- the other party does not accept that?
- the other party just ignores the right of rescission?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can not reverse transactions already included in a block. What you could do is to set up a set of rules in the smart contract that allows for this rescission.

For instance, inside of your system of smart contracts, you can establish that assets can be transferred from one contract to another if some type of proof is provided, then the users are aware that a "legal" decision (proof) can execute a transfer of assets from their accounts. This works as long as the users do not move the assets out of the reach of your system.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear Jaime, thank you very much! Please allow 2 questions: 1. Who controls the legal proof of the right for rescission? How is it ensured that a user does not use the possibility of rescission fraudulently? E.g. the buyer wants to get rid of the contract and claims rescission without any legal reason. 2. When is an asset out of the system. E.g. I buy something and then send it back. Is it sufficient to have a proof of mailing to reverse the contract? Thank you very much, Luri

Comment: 1. This depends on your design. The judge, that decides that it is right to a rescission could be a contract with rules or a third party outside the blockchain 2. If the judge is a contract, then the user should provide valid evidence to the smart contract for it to approve the rescission if a third party is used, the same case applies. 3. An asset is out of the system if, for instance, the reversion implies ether or tokens but these were moved out of the smart contracts of your systems to another account where your smart contract cannot claim it.

Answer (score 0):

Rescission could be implemented as a normal transaction.  Smart contract just need to:

1. ensure that caller is eligible to initiate rescission,
2. reconstruct details of original transaction,
3. execute reverse transaction.

There are different possible approaches for how original transaction details could be reconstructed.  Here are two most obvious:

1. Original transaction stores its details in smart contract storage, rescission transaction loads them from there.
2. Original transaction stores hash of its details in smart contract storage, rescission initiator provides all necessary details.  Rescission transaction loads hash from storage and checks that provided details match it.

Comment: Dear Mikhail, thank you very much! Can you please add how a smart contract can check whether caller is eligible to initiate rescission in case of a complex legal question? Can this question be addresses and decided "outside" of the smart contract?  Thank you very much, Luri

Comment: From reading your question, I thought that "one party has a legal right to rescission", so check is trivial: just compare rescission initiator's address with already known address of this "one party".